# ansible aws_ssm lookup fails with validationexception

Tags: ansible, aws-secrets-manager, aws-ssm

I am trying to look up the password from AWS secret manager, but I am getting a validation error.

below is the asnsible role

```
name: lookup value for password in secrets manager 
 set_fact: password_secret: "{{ `lookup('aws_ssm', '/aws/reference/secretsmanager/v1/myapp/password', region='us-east-1' ) }}"
verbosity: 0`
```

and the is an error

```
failed! => {"msg": "an unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'aws_ssm'. error was a <class 'ansible.errors.ansibleerror'>, original message: ssm lookup exception: an error occurred (validationexception) when calling the getparameters operation: an error occurred while calling one aws dependency service."
```

It works for SSM parameter, I am getting the error only for secretsmanager lookup.
I checked the secrete path and the role of ec2(this role has access to the secrets)

Answer (score 0):

As a [search of their issues](https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/issues/322#issuecomment-817781271) explains, the `ssm` lookup is just for SSM parameters, and the [`aws_secret` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/amazon/aws/aws_secret_lookup.html) is for Secrets Manager access

Feel free to file a bug with them to provide better error messages for what seems to be a common mistake